# System overloaded with 'DTServiceHub' process

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, xcode11

I'm trying to run some tests on a app. The tests are run on a simulator on a mac mini. After few runs the system is overloaded with process and cannot boot any more simulators. I'm getting this error **`An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=67): Unable to boot device due to insufficient system resources. The current system settings are not sufficient to allow booting additional simulators: maxUserProcs: 5568, runningUserProcs: 5312, enforcedProcBuffer: 300`**

After checking the process logs I can see that out of total 4700 processes around 4400 of them are for `DTServiceHub`.

Can someone advice me how to debug it further? I'm using XCode 11.

````
  501 99880     1   0  1Sep20 ??         0:00.07 /Applications/Xcode.11.2.1.11B500.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Resources/DTServiceHub
  501 99924     1   0  1Sep20 ??         0:00.05 /Applications/Xcode.11.2.1.11B500.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Resources/DTServiceHub```

kumar% ps -ef | grep -v grep  | grep 'DTServiceHub' | wc -l
  4464
````